# how do I declare additional property for React class component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I rewrite my React Project with TypeScript. now I know how to declare property interface and state interface for a Class Component, simple like this:

```
export interface ComponentProps {
    propName: string
}

interface ComponentState {
    stateName: number
}

class myComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
...
}
```

but error accur when I do something in componentDidMount() lifecycle:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.customProperty = 26;  // here I could save an id returned by setInterval to cancel it in the componentWillUnmount() for example.
}
```

[ts] Property 'customProperty' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'. [2339]
What can I do to declare additional property correctly, not just simple silence the error.

I've learned the basic of typescript.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export interface CheckoutProps {
    total: number;
    customer: string;
}

interface State {
    isChecking: boolean;
}

class Checkout extends Component<CheckoutProps, State> {
    state = {
        isChecking: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    this.customProperty = 'sean';
    }

    render() {
        return <div>hello</div>;
    }
}

export default Checkout;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class level properties can be defined after the class declartion,

They can be initialized either at the time of declartion or in constructor.

Change your Class To :-

```
class Checkout extends Component<CheckoutProps, State> {
    customProperty:string=''; //Here,you can define your class level properties

    state = {
        isChecking: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    this.customProperty = 'sean';
    }

    render() {
        return <div>hello</div>;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers !!

Comment: Thank you. I never think of customProperty as Class level property, cuz it prefixes with this keyword. I've learned a new thing.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot add property editor, object is not extensible

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it within the class:

```
class myComponent extends React.Component<ComponentProps, ComponentState> {
     private customProperty: string = '';

     componentDidMount() {
        this.customProperty = 'sean';
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your swift help, but new error is prompt said: [ts] Property 'customProperty' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. [2564], how do I solve that?

Comment: I figure out I just need set a default value, thank you.